# nginx chucked_transfer_encoding on/off dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, nginx

is there any way using php to automatically enable/disable the chucked_transfer_encoding without putting it in the nginx Config but in the PHP Script instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First make sure you're using HTTP/1.1.
2. Send the appropriate header: `header('Transfer-encoding: chunked');` followed by a `flush();`.
3. Give the client a content-length for every chunk you're sending over the wire.

Since the questions is more of a conceptual nature and you didn't provide any code to work with, I suppose you don't need an actual implementation. Besides, there are plenty of code samples in the wild, including the use of popular frameworks etc..